# Correct way to mutate initialized objects in python

Tags: python, pygame

I have recently decided to start learning python. For most of my time I have used C++ and some things are very confusing to me.

Here is my code that I have problem with (full code here: http://pastebin.com/tj3qJnvM)

```
class Display:

    def __init__(self, background):
        resolution = (800, 600)    
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
        background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
        background.fill((255, 255, 255))
        background = background.convert()

def init(map, background):
    pygame.init()
    display = Display(background)
    map.draw(background)

def main():
    background = None
    init(map, background)
```

When I call `display = Display(background)` in `init` (line 61), it should initialize background so it can be used on the next line. Instead I get error saying that background is None.

If I understand it correctly it's due to the fact that background was set to None and None is not mutable so it creates local variable background in Display constructor.

How should I approach this situation?

I know it would be best to make background a member of Display class but I want to understand how to create something similar to declaring a pointer/reference in C. And then initialize it in some function. 
This would be useful to pass it then to some functions.

Is it possible in python or is workaround needed every time?

Comment: Please put a [mcve] in the question. Also you're not using `self.` for what I assume are intended to be instance attributes; read a tutorial.

Comment: Sorry, now example should be more readable. I want to initialize background from main inside other function so I don't want to use self in this case.

Comment: Maybe have a read through [section 9, Classes](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html) of the tutorial. Looks like you need to spend some more time learning how to do things the Python way. . ```display``` is an instance of ```Display``` and its attributes are accessed with ```display.attribute```. - But the way you wrote your class, there aren't any instance attributes. You should also probably read through [naming and binding](https://docs.python.org/3/references/executionmodel.html#naming-and-binding).

Comment: Because I don't want it to be attribute of display. I want background to be in main. That's why I pass it as argument to functions

Comment: `return` in Python can send many objects so there is no need to use pointers as arguments - you can simple do `display, background = init()` and `return display, background`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed. I think you're looking for preserved state in class instance variables. Use `self.` if you want to save stuff on the class. Like most languages, variables, unless specifically defined as global, will not affect anything outside their scope. I added `self.` and removed the background variable function parameter.

```
class Display:

    def __init__(self):
        resolution = (800, 600)    
        screen = pygame.display.set_mode(resolution)
        background = pygame.Surface(screen.get_size())
        background.fill((255, 255, 255))
        self.background = background.convert()

def init(map):
    pygame.init()
    display = Display()
    map.draw(display.background) 

def main():
    init(map)
```

Additionally you haven't defined `map` so you're going to have problems with `map.draw`. It only runs because `map` just happens to be a built-in Python function.

EDIT: nevermind, forget what I just said ^.

I see your full code sample defines it.

Comment: For that reason I would advise against using "map" as a parameter name, but technically it shouldn't cause any problems in this very limited case (because it only exists within the scope of a function call)

Comment: Yeah that's exactly what I did and it's working nice. It's much better approach to put background inside class. Thanks!

Edit: you forgot to put self. before other "background" :)

Comment: No, the other `background` variable is just a local variable and does not have a `self.` in front of it. It is only set after it is returned from `.convert()`. Making it a class field is redundant as it will just be overwritten by `self.background = [self.]background.convert()` anyway.